# Loop through JAVA StringTokenizer

Tags: java

please I need help badly. Thank You

I read a text file from my hard disk which contains as follows....

```
void main()
{

    int A = 5;
    int B = 5;
    int C ; 
    C = A + B;
    cout << C ; 

}
```

So, what I need to do is that..
Lets say I have an array of...

```
String []KeyWord = {"void", "main()"};
String []DataType = {"int", "float"};
```

So I want to loop through each token and check whether for example its a key word or a datatype. I used java netBeans and I code as follows

```
int k = 0; int l = 0;

StringTokenizer Tokens;

while ((CurrentLine = ReadFile.readLine()) != null)
{
    Tokens = new StringTokenizer(CurrentLine, " ", true);
    for (int i = 0; Tokens.hasMoreTokens(); i++)
    {
        if (Tokens.nextToken().contains(KeyWord[k]))
        {
            jTextArea1.append(KeyWord[k] + "\n");
            k++;
        } 
        else if (Tokens.nextToken().contains(DataType[l]))
        {
            jTextArea2.append(DataType[l] + "\n");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Goodness gracious learn Java naming conventions, this code is unreadable. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: Be careful, you are making very strange use of the index variables (k, and l) plus you are inadvertently consuming too many tokens in the `if` / `else if` conditions. Why dont you try `Set<String> keywords` instead of `String []KeyWord`? Then you get `if (keywords.contains(token))`, much neater... just some hints.

Comment: So what's your question? Is there an error? Does it not do what you expect?

Comment: You have not made an effort to check theory on parsers, lexical analyzers, etc. Also what is your problem exactly?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)

Comment: I am guys please. I was new to JAVA. Thanks guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, your code won't work. While you're iterating over the tokens you never increment k and l which remain `0` through out; implying that you're always checking for the first keyword and data type only.

#### Recommendations

- Use the simpler `String.split()` instead of `StringTokenizer` which is generally used when you have more than one delimiters and a bit more advanced needs than just a basic split. And since you're passing `returnDelims` as `true` (third parameter) you're receiving your spaces back as your tokens as well (which ins't what you want I suppose).
- Use a `HashSet<String>` to store your keywords/datatypes instead of an Array or ArrayList. This would give you much better performance as compared to iterating the Array or using `ArrayList.contains()`.
- Sample Implementation

  ```
  HashSet<String> keyWords = new HashSet<String>(
          Arrays.asList(new String[] {"void", "main()"}));
  HashSet<String> dataTypes = new HashSet<String>(
          Arrays.asList(new String[] {"int", "float"}));

  String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
  while ((currentLine = readFile.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] tokens= currentLine.split(" ");
      for (String token : tokens) {
          if (keyWords.contains(token)) {
              jTextArea1.append(token + newLine);
          } else if (dataTypes.contains(token)) {
              jTextArea2.append(token + newLine);
          }
      }
   }
  ```

Comment: Thanks very much Ravi, if you have time would you please write me the code in full so that I can understand well. Thanks bro

Comment: How can I use the HashSet<String>. Thanks Ravi

Comment: Ravi what if I want check whether each line of the file ends with semicolon or not?

Comment: Check `if (currentLine.endsWith(";")) { // yes, it does }` in your code.

Comment: If you are there RAVI, this code is not giving me correct value

Comment: while ((CurrentLine = ReadFile.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    lineCount++;
                    if (CurrentLine.endsWith("; "))
                    {
                       
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        jTextArea2.append("Error at line" + lineCount + newLine);
                        
                    }
                          
                
                    
                }

Comment: You have a space after `;` in `"; "`. You can also invert the check and append in `if` block as `if (!CurrentLine.endsWith(";")) { jTextArea2.append("Error at line: " + lineCount + newLine); }`

Comment: Thank you for: "Use the simpler `String.split()` instead of `StringTokenizer`".

Answer (score 0):

First, convert `keyWord` and `dataType` arrays to `ArrayList`.

Then, do something like:

```
while ((currentLine = ReadFile.readLine()) != null) {
   String[] tokens= currentLine.split(" ");
   for (String token : tokens) {
      if (keyWord.contains(token)) {
         jTextArea.append(token);
      }
   } 
    //rest of the code is similar
}
```

Comment: You are most helpfull darijan. How can I declare an arraylist in JAVA. Sorry bro cos I am new to JAVA

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String gkadc[]) {
 
    String s = "the                   sky                     is         ";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     
    StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(s);
      
    for(int i=0;i<( 2*t.countTokens() +1  );i++) {//imp line
        sb.append(t.nextElement()+" ");
    }     
    System.out.println( sb); 
 
} 

//out _   "the sky is"
```

Comment: u can split string with regex , but  heres another way ,in this we will append each element from our token strings , by iterating through it